# Maintain the same average value while respecting ratios

Tags: math

I have such a problem on hand. Imagine there are 5 sliders with a range of values 0 to 100. In the beginning, they are all set to 50, so the average score is 50.

**Goal 1. Maintain average at 50**

Say, if I move the first slider to 70, in order to maintain the average at 50, I decrease the value of the other 4 sliders to 45, i.e. 50 - (20/4) = 45.

**Goal 2. Maintain ratios between individual values**

The above example was easy, because all 4 affected values where equal. However, if I decide to move the 5th slider to 50, I want all the other sliders to adjust so that the ratios between individual values (e.g. slider 1 / slider 2 is 70 / 45 -> 1,5555...) remain the same.

Here's the method I'm considering.

- Step 1. Find the smallest value in the array of affected values (slider 1-4).
- Step 2. Calculate ratios of each slider with the minimum-value-slider.
- Step 3. This gives me a formula avg(ratio1*minV + ratio2*minV + ratio3*minV + *minV + newManualV) = 50
- Step 4. Calculate minV and the remaining values using ratios.

So, in my example, it would be something like this:

```
newManualV = 50 (5th slider)
minV = 45 (any of the 2nd-4th sliders; let's say it's the 2nd)
ratio1 = 1.55556 (1st and minV)
ratio2 = 1 (3rd and minV)
ratio3 = 1 (3rd and minV)

(1.55556*minV + 1*minV + 1*minV + minV + 50) / 5 = 50
4.55556minV = 200
minV = 43.9

New (rounded) slider values are:
68 (43.9 * 1.55556)
44
44
44
50
```

**Question. Is there a better way of doing this?**

Comment: What happens if it's not possible? For example all your sliders are at 90 and then you move one down to 0? Do you just clamp the values to 100 and ignore the fact that the average isn't maintained? Or do you keep the average but ignore the ratios?

Comment: Also there are 4 ratios to maintain plus one average for 5 equations for 5 unknowns. That means you cannot change one slider and it will maintain this value while reaching the goals. It would have to change too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is better?  I think there is an easier way, as you do not need to explicitly calculate the ratio's. Just distribute the difference of the altered slider equally.

Denote the slide values with s1, ..., s5.

Suppose you change s1 with and amount d. Then, calculate s, the sum of the other sliders: s = s2+s3+s4+s5. Now, s2 -= (s2/s)*d.

The sum of s1 to s5 does not change (and so the average), and all other sliders are changed in proportion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Five sliders equals 4 ratios to maintain. For example `x_1/x_2`. This is done only by multiplying all the slider by the same factor.

As soon as you set one value (for example slider #5) then all the others have to scale accordingly to maintain the ratios.

```
old_x_5 = x_5
x_5 = (new value)
scale = x_5/old_x_5
x_4 = x_4*scale
x_3 = x_3*scale
x_2 = x_2*scale
x_1 = x_1*scale
```

Now you have to re-scale everything in order to meet the average goal

```
average = (x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5)/5
if average>0
  scale = 50/average
  x_5 = x_5*scale
  x_4 = x_4*scale
  x_3 = x_3*scale
  x_2 = x_2*scale
  x_1 = x_1*scale
else
  (now what?)
```

This changes the new `x_5` to a value needed for the average goal instead of the user input. Also what happens if any of the sliders need to be over 100 to maintain the average.

Comment: Hi. I think your solution is correct as well, although I haven't tested it explicitly. One note - the value of dependent sliders will never exceed 0 or 100. Because if there are only two sliders, the second will always move the same amount as the first, which is within the 0-100 range. If there are more sliders, then the dependent sliders will always move by an amount which is smaller than the slider being moved.